# jquery variable value is saying undefiend

Tags: jquery

The variable $x10Device says undefined in the if statement why?  In the rest of function it has a value, how do I get it to keep it's value.

```
$("button.checkStatus").click(function () {
    //This Ajax checks the current on/off status of the passed X10 code
    $('.checkStatus').each(function (i, obj) {
        $x10Device = $(this).data("x10");
        //var data = "url=http://192.168.0.34:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d=C5" //& $x10Device ; //this is passed in the device toggle

        var data = "url=http://192.168.0.34:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d=" + $x10Device; //this is passed in the device toggle

        $.ajax({
            url: "urlencode.php",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                myd = $('<span />').html(data).find("#Result").text();
                var Nmyd = myd.charAt(3);
                if (Nmyd == '2') {
                    $($x10Devic).data('src', 'lightbulbon.png')
                } else {
                    $('img').attr('src', 'lightbulboff.png')
                };
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `$x10Device`? Try using `console.log($x10Device);` and see what it outputs.

Comment: How about just selecting a simpler variable name, and formatting the code properly, should solve most of the errors.

Comment: As a sidenote, you're passing an entire URL with querystring and the works, as `data` to $.ajax ? How does that work on the serverside !

Comment: What is the output of `console.log( $(this) );`? Where do you set this value? Is it on every object with the `checkstatus` class? Does `obj.data("x10");` work?

Comment: @adeneo, it might be a switch at the server side, where POST values are optional

Comment: @adeneo,I am passing it to a function of PHP called Curl and it process's it fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the entire problem, but you have a typo:

`$x10Device` vs. `$x10Devic`

Comment: Spent an age looking at the code and didn't see the typo but it didn't correct it.  The variable holds "c5" for example the AJAX call Returns C5:3;  3 tells me that device c5 is currently on and I use the if statement to replace the img with a light bulb on jpg, to represent this.  Sorry but I don't see how a simpler name would work, baring my own typo's!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `$x10Device` is wrong (as implied by the context). You will get rid of these errors using two variables to avoid confusion: `$Device = $(this); $x10 = $Device.data('x10');`:

```
$("button.checkStatus").click(function(){
    $('.checkStatus').each(function (i,obj){
        /**
         * These changes assume that $x10Device was NOT a global variable
         */
        var $Device = $(this),
        $x10 = $Device.data("x10"),
        data = "url=http://192.168.0.34:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d=" + $x10;

        $.ajax({
            url: "urlencode.php",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                myd = $('<span />').html(data).find("#Result").text();
                var Nmyd = myd.charAt(3);
                if (Nmyd == '2') {
                    $Device.data('src', 'lightbulbon.png')
                } else {
                    $('img').attr('src', 'lightbulboff.png')
                };
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: $x10 is undefined isn't $(this) the button?  The button has no data attribute value, only the img tags have the data attribute.

Comment: I don't know what `$Device` is, from the code I can only infer that it's a DOM elemento with `class="checkStatus"`. `$Device` is each one of those elements, `$x10` is the `x10` jQuery data associated to it.

Comment: No my mistake got that working, thanks, it seems to be dropping out in Ajax just looking into why

Comment: With these changes in place when I step through the code, when I get to the success: line it hits the error function but doesn't display the alert and then to the start of the loop??